# MySQL conditional variable inside text field

Tags: mysql

This might seem like a strange one, but can you store a conditional variable inside a text field (or something that can be made to work like one)?

I'm creating a notification system that groups notification by date and type, so if 2 or more of the same type are created in the same day it will group the notifications together and provide a count (e.g. Person1 and 3 others have done something).

The notification messages are stored in a table as a template e.g.

```
[[value]] has just done something
```

`[[value]]` is then replaced with  Person1's name (and `count` OTHERS) by using

```
    REPLACE(t1.message, 
        '[[value]]', 
        IF(t1.value_as_user=1, 
            CONCAT(t1.forename, ' ', t1.surname, IF((count((t1.id + DATE(t1.date)))-1)<>0, 
                CONCAT(' and ', (count((t1.id + DATE(t1.date)))-1), ' other'), 
                '')), 
            t1.value)) as 'message'
```

The only problem with this is it would mean that grammatically the message would no longer make sense i.e. "Person1 and 2 others has just done something" should now be "Person1 and 2 others **have** just done something"

Is there a way to select a string within a text field (like I have done with `[[value]]`) except have it where it would be something like `[[has/have]]` and depending on the count the correct one could chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can change the sentence to avoid the grammatical variability:

> Something has been done by Person1 and 2 others

(If you read *The Elements of Style by Strunk & White*, you may be conditioned to recoil at the passive voice. The above trick may seem like cheating. [But don't let them bully you.](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497))

Otherwise, no, there's no function in MySQL that can analyze a string and find out its grammatical usage in English and automatically conjugate verbs.

You could make [[has/have]] be another meta-field in your string, and then replace it with another expression based on the count.

But frankly, I wouldn't do the string formatting in an SQL expression. Not only for this reason, but because string-manipulation in SQL is clumsy compared to *literally any other language* (except Java of course).